# Relocate default directory away from mywork in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

When one googles something like this it pops out that one needs to change either JDEV_USER_DIR or set ide.user.dir parameter in Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\ide\bin\ide.boot file, but this is explicitly wrong. Changing ide.user.dir parameter relocates files where JDeveloper saves its parameters, not default folder for my projects. So, can someone give me the correct answer how do I replace the default folder for my projects (that is after installing JDeveloper)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jdeveloper.exe -J-Dide.user.dir=C:\myWork
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in the wizard for application creation lets you choose where to place the application. I believe that after you set this for one application the next ones will follow along to the same directory by default.

Answer (score 0):

According to the first link I found, http://www.catgovind.com/jdeveloper/where-is-jdeveloper-user-home-directory-in-windows/ and the explanation on https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/how-to-find-and-reset-the-system11-x-x-x-folder-for-a-jdeveloper-installation/ the way to set the working directory is to set the environment variable JDEV_USER_HOME. I set it to the value: %USERPROFILE%\Documents\JDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer here: https://agungor.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/how-to-change-default-open-application-folder-of-jdeveloper/

Just navigate to C:\Users....\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.62.29\o.jdeveloper\applications.xml and change workDirectory attribute